# Sorting nested Array in MongoDB using aggregate

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, nested

I am trying to sort the nested array "subCategoryList on top of sorting by _id on the parent document. Newbie to mongo. Any help will be appreciated

Here is sample documents:

```
[
    {
        "_id": 1000,
        "name": "Automobiles",
        "parentId": "",
        "helpText": "Year, Brand, Model, Color, Size"
    },
    {
        "_id": 1004,
        "name": "RV / Campers",
        "parentId": 1000,
        "helpText": ""
    },
    {
        "_id": 1001,
        "name": "Car / SUV / Truck",
        "parentId": 1000,
        "helpText": ""
    }
]
```

Here is what I tried:

```
db.Category.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "parentId": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "Category", "localField": "_id", "foreignField": "parentId", "as": "subCategoryList"
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            _id: 1
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

But I get:

```
    {
    "_id" : 17000,
    "name" : "Music",
    "parentId" : "",
    "helpText" : "Help Text - Brand, Model, Title",
    "subCategoryList" : [
        {
            "_id" : 17001,
            "name" : "DVD / Blu-ray",
            "parentId" : 17000,
            "helpText" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 17002,
            "name" : "Player",
            "parentId" : 17000,
            "helpText" : ""
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 20000,
    "name" : "Sports Gear",
    "parentId" : "",
    "helpText" : "Help Text - Brand, Model, Gear Type, Size, Color,",
    "subCategoryList" : [
        {
            "_id" : 20002,
            "name" : "Football",
            "parentId" : 20000,
            "helpText" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 20007,
            "name" : "Tennis",
            "parentId" : 20000,
            "helpText" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 20008,
            "name" : "Cricket",
            "parentId" : 20000,
            "helpText" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 20004,
            "name" : "Hockey",
            "parentId" : 20000,
            "helpText" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 20003,
            "name" : "Golf",
            "parentId" : 20000,
            "helpText" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 20006,
            "name" : "Basketball",
            "parentId" : 20000,
            "helpText" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 20005,
            "name" : "Soccer",
            "parentId" : 20000,
            "helpText" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 20010,
            "name" : "Camping / Hiking",
            "parentId" : 20000,
            "helpText" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 20009,
            "name" : "Cycling",
            "parentId" : 20000,
            "helpText" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 20001,
            "name" : "Baseball",
            "parentId" : 20000,
            "helpText" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 20012,
            "name" : "Skiing",
            "parentId" : 20000,
            "helpText" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 20011,
            "name" : "Swimming",
            "parentId" : 20000,
            "helpText" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 20099,
            "name" : "Other",
            "parentId" : 20000,
            "helpText" : ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.hardwares.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$subCategoryList"},
    {$sort: {"subCategoryList._id": 1}},
    {$group: {_id:"$_id", subCategoryList: {$push:"$subCategoryList"}}}
]);
```

It could be helps you, try like this...
May be it didn't work but it gives an idea

Answer (score 1):

Mongo doesn't have a built in function to sort an inner array, However Mongo v4.4 introduces the [`$function`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/function/index.html) aggregation operator. this allows us to use custom javascript functions within a pipeline.

You could use it like so:

```
db.Category.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            "subCategoryList":
                {
                    $function: {
                        body: function (categories) {
                            return categories.sort((a, b) => a._id - b._id);
                        },
                        args: ["$subCategoryList"],
                        lang: "js"
                    }
                }
        }
    }
])
```

For lesser Mongo versions you will have to first `$unwind` the array. then `$sort` it and finally constructing the original structure or in your case because you are `$lookup`ing the inner array you could use the [other](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) `$lookup` syntax introduced at v3.6 to `$sort` within the `$lookup`:

```
db.Category.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "parentId": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "Category",
            let: {id: "$_id"},
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $eq: ["$$id", "$parentId"]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $sort: {
                        _id: 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "as": "subCategoryList"
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            _id: 1
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. Will try this from the Java Client as well.